# Jasmine Expected jasmine.createSpyObj error

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I am trying to mock and trying to satisfy else condition for below method but I am getting error as **Expected spy modalService.open not to have been called**

Here is the component code

After updating the below line component.isError = true;

Highlighting the If block was not coming but still the error is available

```
public importDeals(upload, list) {
  this.fileName = '';
   let ngbModalOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
    backdrop : 'static',
    keyboard : false,
    windowClass: 'custom-class'
};   
if (!this.isError) {
  this.uploadModalRef = this.modalService.open(upload, ngbModalOptions);
}
this.tempContingency = list;
}
```

Below is the current unit test case (Jasmine)

```
it('should import deals', () => {
  // component.importDeals;
  // expect(component.importDeals('upload','list')).toBeUndefined();
  component.importDeals;
  component.uploadModalRef = jasmine.createSpyObj('uploadModalRef', ['close']);
  let mockOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
    backdrop : 'static',
    keyboard : false,
    windowClass: 'custom-class'
  };
  const mockConfirm = 'confirm-template';
  component.importDeals(mockConfirm,'');
  expect(modalService.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockConfirm, mockOptions);
});
it('should not import deals', () => { 
  component.importDeals; 
  component.modalService = jasmine.createSpyObj('modalService',['open'])
  const mockConfirm = 'confirm-template'; 

  component.importDeals(mockConfirm,''); 
  expect(modalService.open).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); 
  });
```

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Set the value of `isError` to true otherwise that if block will always execute.

```
it('should not import deals', () => { 
  component.importDeals; 
  component.modalService = jasmine.createSpyObj('modalService',['open']);
  component.isError = true; // <- this line
  const mockConfirm = 'confirm-template'; 

  component.importDeals(mockConfirm,''); 
  expect(modalService.open).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); 
});
```

Comment: the If block is now ok but I am still getting the error in console as 

Expected spy modalService.open not to have been called

Comment: If that error is showing up it means the method is being called, which means the code inside that if block executes. A good way to confirm is to put a console.log inside the if block so be certain if it executes or not.